# I can't run Ubuntu 12.10 well on my Sony P series

Tags: vaio, sony, gma500

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on a Sony Vaio VGN-610t with W. Vista.
Processor
Intel® (1.33GHz)
Intel® System Controller Hub US15W Chipset
Cache Memory
512KB integrated into the second level
Bus speed
533MHz 
Graphic Card
Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 500
Memory RAM
2GB DDR2 SDRAM 
Hard disk
80GB
It was installed correctly but it runs so very slow. I'm new on this. There is something I can do to fix this? Or I'll have to (someway) delete it from my computer?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Since Unity 2D is dropped since Ubuntu 12.10, all devices run Untiy 3D, also low-powered machines which uses the CPU when the graphics card isn't capable enough to run the Unity interface, which makes it very slow tot use.